# Zipcodes in R to be reduced

Tags: r

I have a dataset which has 17854 distinct levels of zipcodes spread across USA . Is there any function in R or any method using which I can reduce the number of levels ? I need to reduce it to less than 500 distinct levels.

Thanks,
Minal

Comment: What do you mean by levels? Zip codes aren't nested, and they're definitely not 17854 degrees of nested.

Comment: Drop the trailing 2 digits divide by 2 and truncated. Viola.

Comment: Levels as in, Zip code in my dataset is a categorical variable and it has 17854 distinct Zipcode values so referred them as levels. I am new to analytics. I might be wrong in using the appropriate word !

Comment: Subset by state.  Assign a weight to each state, based on population, and split up the 500 zip codes accordingly.??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   trunc( as.numeric( substr( zipvec, 1,3))/2 )
```

Comment: Thank you!. I also wondered if there any way in which I can map the truncated zipcodes to alphabetic city/state names automatically ? Like a function or something which pulls up data from Maps?

Answer (score 0):

This data might be useful for you.  It has data for population, city, county, lat/long, state, type, etc.

```
> url <- "http://www.unitedstateszipcodes.org/zip_code_database.csv"
> tmp <- tempfile()
> download.file(url, tmp)
> zips <- read.csv("zip_code_database.csv")
> unlink(tmp)
> zip.sub <- zips[zips$type == "STANDARD", 
                  c("zip", "state", "latitude", "longitude")]

> zip.sub[sample(1:nrow(zip.sub), 10, FALSE), ]
##         zip state latitude longitude
## 12121 28649    NC    36.33    -81.23
## 4129  11359    NY    40.79    -73.77
## 22577 51026    IA    42.23    -96.09
## 40251 95480    CA    38.64   -123.37
## 23441 53804    WI    42.89    -90.92
## 40574 96022    CA    40.33   -122.45
## 13589 31548    GA    30.79    -81.66
## 40557 96001    CA    40.60   -122.46
## 40428 95757    CA    38.35   -121.42
## 4531  12205    NY    42.66    -73.79
```

When we apply the truncating function posted by @BondedDust, we get

```
> trn <- trunc(as.numeric(substr(zip.sub$zip, 1,3))/2)
> length(unique(trn))
## [1] 442
```